# Creating trigger in apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm unable to find what is the issue with this trigger. I'm getting this issue while complicating.

Compilation failed, line 6 (17:42:44) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following: ;

````
BEFORE insert or update on "JANC"
for each row
begin
    if inserting and :new.id is null then


:new.created_by         := nvl(v('APP_USER'), USER);
:new.created            := localtimestamp;
        end if;
    end if;
    if updating then
        :new.updated_by         := nvl(v('APP_USER'), USER);
        :new.updated            := localtimestamp;
    end if;
END;```
````

Comment: You have two `end if` lines at the end of the first `if`.  Remove one of them.

Comment: And if you're on 12c+, consider these concepts https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/

Comment: You could use https://apex.oracle.com/quicksql/. With the settings

```

# apex: true
# auditcols: true

```

You can generate this trigger in seconds